# Calculate failure probability for given time series data

Tags: time-series, probability, predictive-models, failure-rate, sensor-data

I am trying to find a way to calculate the likelihood that a machine will fail. Specifically, I would like to receive a prediction such as, "There is a 28% chance that this machine will fail within the next 3 days." To do this, I have a time series of sensor data and a known limit for failure.

For instance, let's say I have a motor powering a device, and I have data on the motor's power consumption over time. I also have the power limit for the motor, and I assume that the power required to move the device will increase over time. In an ideal scenario, the power increase over time would be linear, allowing me to calculate the exact date of failure when the power required meets the motor's power limit.

However, in reality, there will be errors and noise in the sensor data, making it impossible to determine the exact date of failure. Instead, I can use a linear fit to calculate when the power limit is reached, but the result will only give me the most likely date of failure.

Therefore, I would like to obtain a probability of failure over time correlation from the data I have. For instance, I would like to know the probability of failure within the next 24 hours (12%), the next 2 days (19%), the next 3 days (35%), and so on, up to the next 10 days (98%) or so.

While I know others have likely faced this issue before, I have not been able to find a suitable solution or suggestion. I am hoping you can provide me with some guidance or links to potential solutions.